# Can't match regex in string equality

Tags: bash

I just can't match the $move with regex, move is a chess move f.e. "a2 a4". It always goes to else part... thanks for any help

```
read move
if [[ "$move" =~ "[a-h][1-8] [a-h][1-8]" ]] ; then
  CheckMove "$move" 1
else 
  printf "Invalid move format \n"
fi
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't quote your regex pattern inside the `if` condition. That makes it act like a simple string equality test. Use an unquoted variable:

```
  read move
  pattern="[a-h][1-8] [a-h][1-8]"
  if [[ $move =~ $pattern ]] ; then
```

Inside double square brackets you don't need to quote your `$move` variable either.

Also, don't use single square brackets in a Bash-specific script.

```
    if [[ $move_valid = true ]] ; then
```

I don't see where that variable gets set, by the way.